# Typescript interface and creating an object of that interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am create a small application in typescript, where I am using interfaces to 
create objects of specific types like the following `UserProfile` interface.

both the `interface` and the `fulfill` function are defined in `user-profile.ts` file.

```
export interface UserProfile  {

    readonly titel_id: number;
    readonly user_name: string;
    readonly email: string;
    readonly first_name: string;
    readonly last_name: string;
    readonly phone: string;
    readonly fax: string;

}

export function fulfill({  titel_id, user_name, email, first_name, last_name,  phone, fax }: any): UserProfile {
    return {

        titel_id,
        user_name,
        email,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        phone,
        fax
    }
}
```

I am calling this function from my `UserMdoel's find` function which contains all the fields of user table and fulfill function  gives only those fields which are speficied in interface. But as you can see that I have to write the fields 3 times

once in interface, then in object destructring and then in return statement. It means if I later have to change the fields I have to change this on 3 places.

Is there a better way to solve this issue?

Comment: Casting your object to a specific type should suffice `let profile: UserProfile = <UserProfile> object;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my answer.

Interfaces do not survive the transpile to javascript. One thing you could do is to create an array with all the names and use this array to automatically copy over all fields.

You still have to maintain the fields in two places though.

```
export const USER_PROFILE_FIELDS: string[] = [
    'titel_id',
    'user_name',
    'email',
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'phone',
    'fax',
];
export interface UserProfile  {

    readonly titel_id: number;
    readonly user_name: string;
    readonly email: string;
    readonly first_name: string;
    readonly last_name: string;
    readonly phone: string;
    readonly fax: string;

}

export function fulfill(template: any): UserProfile {
    return <UserProfile>USER_PROFILE_FIELDS.reduce(
        (object, key) => object[key] = template[key],
        {}
    );
}
```

If you need this for multiple interfaces, you could create a higher order function which creates the fulfill function for you. Like that you don't need to manually create a fulfill function for each case. Here is an example:

```
// This function accepts the fields you want to use and returns your fulfill function
export function createFullfill<ResultingType>(fields: string[]) {
    return function(template: any) {
        return <ResultingType>fields.reduce(
            (object, key) => object[key] = template[key],
            {}    
        );
    } 
} 

// Fulfill function for UserProfile
export const fulfillUserProfile = createFullfill<UserProfile>(USER_PROFILE_FIELDS);
// Fulfill function for Project
export const fulfillProject = createFullfill<Project>(PROJECT_FIELDS);
```

Comment: As I wrote that the Object I am providing all all the fields of a table. Which are much more than what I want to return.

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad, I missed that part.

Comment: I updated my answer, please have a look if this better serves your needs.